# MUD source code

Tags: open-source, source-code, mud

I haven't been able to find a lot of the old, open source mud source codes.  I find the way they did things very applicable to text-based/browser based games, and I'd love to be able to skim through parts of 'em for inspiration.

For instance, we have this huge list of muds and the relationships between them, but little by way of access to source code.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD_trees

Often (I'm looking at you, dikumud, http://www.dikumud.com/links.aspx ) the sites of the mud itself doesn't even have a working link to the source.

https://github.com/alexmchale/merc-mud has a copy of merc that I found, which certainly contains other works within it's history, but the pickings seems sparse.

Does anyone have better resources for gaining access to MUD source code than these?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://mudbytes.net/ was established for exactly the purpose you're looking for.

Comment: Great, I'll check out what it has when I have the time.

Comment: Yeah, looks to have the biggest list of mud sources I've seen.

Answer (score 3):

## http://www.andreasen.org/newmud/

**Looks like a good resource, with a list of over 30 different open source MUDs.**

Just for reference I found this by searching Open Source MUD on google.

Comment: A lot of the links there are broken and the site overall hasn't been updated in years. It does have a couple of interesting spots, though.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of an old question, but in case you're looking, there's also this (started out as a simple text adventure engine and is now taking a MUD direction): https://github.com/crankycyclops/trogdor

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically for games, but LambdaMOO (MOO = MUD, Object Oriented) source is available [here](http://www.moo.mud.org/). You need both the server, which implements networking and command parsing, and a minimal (“core”) database, which implements players, rooms, movement, messaging. To build a new game on top of this, you would build on the core, but you probably won't need to modify the server.